# Why when changing field required parameter to false field is still required?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to dinamicly change city field from required to non-required with ajax in my woocommerce checkout.
Ajax callback function:

```
function my_action_callback(){
    WC()->checkout->checkout_fields['billing']['billing_city']['required'] = false;
    $fase = WC()->checkout->checkout_fields;
    wp_send_json($fase);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
```

Ajax function:

```
$(document).on('change', '#shipping_method_0', function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    $.post(ajaxurl, {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'data': {'val':v}
        }, function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
});
```

and devtool console screenshot

[image: screensot]

And after that when i submit the checkout form this field is still required by form response, even if this field is removed from html with devtool.

Comment: My guess is it it caching the old javascript.  Try Control - F5 to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

It's still being required within wc's php. [Add a filter](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-2) disabling this requirement.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['billing_city']['required'] = false;
     return $fields;
}
```